# HTML canvas rectangle aliasing with whole pixel values on hi-res monitor

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an HTML canvas that I am drawing stock ticker candles on. When displayed with a `window.devicePixelRatio` of 1, everything is fine; I make sure to render on whole pixel values so that all the rectangles, and lines are drawn cleanly:

[image]

When looking at this when the `window.devicePixelRatio` is not 1, the method of just using `Math.floor` for the pixel value no longer works, as the `window.devicePixelRatio` can be a factional value.

For example, when looking at this on a 4k monitor, with a `window.devicePixelRatio` of 1.5, the candles render as such:

[image]

As you can see, those same candles now have aliasing around their edges which I would like to get rid of. I have narrowed it down (I think) that in order to render an edge without aliasing, the pixel value provided multiplied by the pixel ratio needs to be a whole number: ie. providing an x pixel of 1 would not work, because, `1 * 1.5 = 1.5`, but a value of 2 would, because, `2 * 1.5 = 3` which is a whole value.

In the picture below, the left candle has an x coordinate of 2, whereas the right candle has an x coordinate of 9. `2 * 1.5 = 3`, but `9 * 1.5 = 13.5` so it gets aliased.

[image]

Is there a simple general mathematical solution to be able to compute what pixel value I should provide when I call `fillRect`, `stroke`, etc so that I won't get this aliasing? Ie. a function where if I passed in `9`, I would get back `10` if I had a `window.devicePixelRatio` of 1.5; basically rounding up to nearest x pixel value that wouldn't give me aliasing.

Edit code reference for how I am scaling the canvas:

```js
this._canvas.nativeElement.style.width = `${this._width}px`;
this._canvas.nativeElement.style.height = `${this._height}px`;

const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;

this._canvas.nativeElement.width = Math.floor(this._width * dpr);
this._canvas.nativeElement.height = Math.floor(this._height * dpr);

this._context.scale(dpr, dpr);
```

Comment: Do you set your canvas size accordingly to the pixel ratio? You need to manually do `canvas.width *= devicePixelRatio` (same with `height`), and then scale down with CSS `canvas { width: $expected-width$px; height:... }`. With a non integer pixel ratio, you may need `image-rendering: pixelated` too.

Comment: I did that as outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio. I don't want to set it to pixelated, because, lines that are drawn on the chart look horrible

Comment: Could you please share (a bit) of your code? Do you go as far as setting the `ctx.scale()` there? It's unclear why the lines would look horrible.

Comment: Added an edit for how I am scaling the canvas. This is in Angular, not purely javascript, but basically the same. I'm sure the scaling is correct, because, when I have the browser on my 1080p monitor, and zoom in/out in chrome the scaling works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are scaling the whole context through `ctx.scale()`. This is indeed the easiest way generally, but this also means that with a non-integer pixel ratio the canvas context will itself convert your integer coordinates to floating ones.

Instead you will want to perform the scaling yourself and round where needed.

```js
const dPR = devicePixelRatio;
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width *= dPR;
canvas.height *= dPR;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
/**
 * Scale the coordinate to the current pixel ratio
 * Does not round. To be used with methods that don't require
 * to fall on integer coords (e.g non straight poly-lines)
 */
const s = (val) => val * devicePixelRatio;
/**
 * Scale the coordinate to the current pixel ratio, rounded to the nearest integer.
 */
const r = (val) => Math.round(s(val));
// Draw a rect using rounded coords
ctx.fillRect(r(50), r(50), r(1), r(75));
```

```css
canvas { width: 300px; height: 150px; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks!